# If I assign the results of a jQuery selector to a variable, how can I further filter that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
var startDate = $(".startdate");
```

..which should select all elements with the class 'startdate'.

I then try to do the following:

```
startDate(".nodate").hide();
```

...to hide any elements with the 'nodate' css class but this fails.

I'm just guessing at syntax here, what silly mistake am I making?

Edit: the 'nodate' elements are not at the same level as the 'startdate' elements. I should have posted an XHTML snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways :

```
$('.startdate').find('.nodate').hide();
$('.nodate','.startdate').hide()
$('.startdate > .nodate').hide()
$('.startdate').children('.nodate').hide()
$('.nodate').filter(':parent(is(.startdate))')
```

My preferred way is the first one, i saw the second one somewhere but didn't used it. I can't remember any other way yet. When i remember then i will update the post.

Comment: I don't think the second one is valid - you did say you haven't used it. The first works great, thanks.

Comment: thanks, @Neil for accepting my answer. 2nd one also works I testes it yours question page in stackoverflow. Just past this code in console $('.container','.question-page').hide(‘slow’) . You will see the magic :). The second parameter takes the container the first.

Comment: `'.startdate > .nodate'`, `children()`, and the `filter(:parent...)` suggestions only find immediate children. The first two find any subelement. Since the behavior is different you may consider editing the answer...

Comment: @orip, thanks for explaining. Is it only in first level or not? @neil didn't mention, so i added those option. It's better to have many options, isn't it :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
startDate.filter('.nodate').hide();
```

Comment: 'filter' does not find any child elements which have the class 'nodate' though?

Comment: `filter` filters the original set, it doesn't search for subelements. If you want the subelements (wasn't clear from the question) then `find` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want: (If to hide ALL elements with class nodate)

```
$(".nodate").hide()
```

Answer (score -1):

startDate is not a function, it's a jQuery object. What you are trying to do is:

```
startDate.filter(".nodate").hide();
```

Which is the same as using directly:

```
$(".startdate.nodate").hide();
```

But ready your question again makes me think it's not very clear ;-)
Are you trying to hide elements that have both startdate AND nodate classes?

Edit: messed up has() with filter(), sorry.

Comment: -1, `has()` would keep elements with *subelements* containing the "nodate" class

Comment: Yeah, I must be tired, thanks for pointing this out @orip, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Looks like you may have botched the formatting a bit, though. :)